# Can't display list of users in PUG/JADE

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am trying to show list of users in PUB. This is my code

```
- var users = !{users};

h1 UserList
    for user in users
        a(href='/deleteuser/' + user.id) user.name user.surname
```

This is rendering code

```
var users = userDatabase.listUsers();

// Render a pug file.
var result = pug.renderFile('userlist.pug', {
    users:users
});

res.send(result);
```

But only header is shown despite the user list is not empty(I have checked it). Can someone help, how can I show list of users on PUG in my example?
How to correct code?

Comment: Have you tried `each user in users` instead of `for`?

Comment: @Scarysize Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using this

```
h1 UserList
p Below you will see list of users.
br
each user in users
    p= user.name + " " + user.surname + "  "
        a(href='/deleteuser/' + user.id) Delete
```